# ListView FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

on this line:

```
list_view.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

I've initiated the list_view and adapter1, I don't know why I'm getting this error.

and I have initialized list_view right after setContentView:

```
list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

Can anyone help me out on this please, if you need more information I will provide it. Thanks in advance.

Edit to add whole code for MainActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_fragment);

    Context context=getApplicationContext();

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ListView list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();


    String[] values = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
    final String[] shoes = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shoe_items);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }


    //main category
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);



    for (int i = 0; i < shoes.length; ++i) {
        list1.add(shoes[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter1 = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {


            setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_fragment);
            if (position == 0) {

                list_view.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: show us where you initialise `adapter1`...because in this piece of code there is no declaration

Comment: I edited to add more, I think the problem have to do with the fact that I've two adapters, one to set the contents for a ListView in one layout, and another to set ListView in another layout. but I'm not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code inside `onClick()` you are calling `setContentView()` again, this will overwrite the previous layout and replaces with the new one.

There should be ListView with id `listView2` layout file `subcategory_fragment.xml` 
and you have to reinitialise the listview. because entire layout is redrawn

add this line

```
final ListView list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_fragment);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Harshikesh, that did the job, and thanks for explaining your answer also.